# How can I get the event in partial-match-filter changed or modified event in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I wanted to set the flag on this particular filter input changed event in ag-grid but I'm not event getting this event using jQuery for the filter class and sub classes.
I wish if someone can help me to log in console on input or alert on the input.
[You can fork and try here][1] [1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/L8yTDJBr7A08tc7T

Comment: So you want to log each time the filter input is changed?

Comment: Yes actually I wanted to set a flag on that particular event